# R-Package "shiny". How to quit a process?

Tags: r, shiny, kill-process

I just discovered the R-package called `shiny`.

I do

```
require(shiny)

     # Loading required package: shiny

runExample("02_text")

     # Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7313
```

and my web browser opened. When I close the tab, the window or the application (safari in my case), the R process doesn't get killed. And the only solution I found to kill this process is to quit R. If I were to use R through the Bash I could probably just do `CTRL-c` but I suppose that a better solution should exist.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Shiny, but have you tried `Esc`?

Comment: No I haven't tried `Esc` and that solved my issue. That was too easy, I couldn't thing of that! Can you make an answer out of your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing the `Esc` key, that usually aborts the running task.